# 'ECONNREFUSED' when trying to using socket to connect to remote computer over TCP

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm having some trouble trying to connect to a remote machine using node.js net API. This code works perfectly locally, but when I try and test it with another person's machine, it gives me the error: 'ECONNREFUSED'

This is the server side code.

```js
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1'; //local host
var PORT = 18000;

net.createServer(function(sock) {
    
    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);
    
    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');
        
    });
    
    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });
    
}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);

// using sockets to connect to another computer on TCP
```

This is the client side code:

```js
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1'; //change this to IP address of the computer I'm trying to connect to
var PORT = 18000; 

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client 
    client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');

});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {
    
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    // Close the client socket completely
    client.destroy();
    
});

client.on('error', function(data){
 console.log('connection error');

});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are listening on localhost, so unless the client is running on the same machine, it won't work.
Try listening on the IP address that the remote machine has access to, or try listening on all addresses (not sure how it works on js, but on C passing the host address as NULL or empty string(depending on platform) does the trick).

Comment: Also check firewalls as they might block communication.

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNREFUSED` means that the server isn't listening on the port that the client is trying to reach. Check the server system, to see if server application has opened the port for listening.

Use tools like `netstat` or equivalent to see the opened TCP ports in the server machine.

Comment: That is not true

Comment: @ProllyGeek, can you please eloborate? Help me understand why my answer is not true.

Comment: Because simply it means connection was refused not that server is not listening on the port! connection can be refused for many reasons(e.g trying to connect to same port you are already connected to)

Check this table out:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0144b/BABCHBGH.html

Comment: What happens if a client tries and the server isn't listening on the port? And no way connection to same port already connected result in ECONNREFUSED . Why shouldn't TCP not allow another connection ? Note: Server application can refuse - thats a different matter. The table you referred to does not say anything substantial. I still think my answer was correct.

Comment: if you modify your answer to say it may be one of reasons (which is true) then I will absloutely retract my downvote!